# Reference Request: Surveys on attacks on security schemes

Tags: reference-request, cr.crypto-security

I am new to provable security and am working on cryptanalysis of a certificate free signature scheme.

Unfortunately, I don't have much knowledge about finding attacks on schemes. It would be very helpful if someone can point me to a survey or other reference to study about cryptanalysis and basically develop some intuition to attack an scheme.

Comment: The _first_ thing to do is try putting together a [reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provable_security#In_Cryptography) to some standard problem(s). $\hspace{.92 in}$ That may give you a clue for what attacks there are. $\:$

Comment: I highly recommend taking a look at the series of articles called [Another Look](http://anotherlook.ca/). I've read and recommend the one titled "Another look at HMQV," but I think "Another look at provable security I & II" will also be useful for you. (It is worth mentioning that these articles raised a series of disputes among the cryptography society; see http://www.sigcrap.org/2007/09/14/the-koblitz-controversy/.)

Comment: "finding attacks on schemes" is much too broad.  There are many different kinds of schemes in cryptography, and the methods of cryptanalysis are very different from scheme to scheme.  (For instance, cryptanalysis of symmetric-key systems tends to be very different from that of public-key systems.)  You might start with the book *Algorithmic Cryptanalysis* by Antoine Joux.  But really, the question is much too broad: one could write an entire book on the subject, and people have.  Lastly: don't forget about [Crypto.SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com).

Comment: You might find [this question](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/453/1037) to be a helpful starting point. I agree with @D.W. that as stated your question seems too broad.